# jQuery extend with prototypes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am relatively new to jQuery and JavaScript and have a question regarding the functionality of `$.extend`.
I am using `extend` to overwrite the prototype of a class that extends a "base class".
Lets call the base `Parent` and the the children/extend classes `A` and `B`.
Now when I use `$.extend(true, A.prototype, {someObject: {extraKey: 'value'}});` it seems also the Prototype of `Parent` is changed regarding the contents of `someObject`, resulting in really odd behavior if several objects/classes inherit from parents. Also this only happens if the "deep" extending is used.

I managed to avoid this problem by extending an empty object with the respective prototype and then using the return value of extend as the new prototype. E.g. `A.prototype = $.extend(true, {}, A.prototype, {someObject: {extraKey: 'value'}});`

To show the problem I created this small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8UtF/12/

The actual question: Is there a way to get around the empty objects and stuff to just go `extend(true, X.prototype, {});`

Comment: I am pretty new to javascript so I cant really explain how ever its called with this prototyping stuff.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the code, in the fiddle. It might be clearer than my confused words. It's something I specially wrote for this so not some weird code from another project.

Comment: `A.prototype = new Parent();` - We don't do this anymore. Use `A.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );`

Comment: I will regard this for the future but it is not related to the problem.

Comment: Also, `$.extend()`, not `$().extend()`. It's a static method.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, when initializing `A.prototype`, you want to leave `Parent.prototype.someObject` as it is (i.e. *not* modify it), while its properties should be **copied** to `A.prototype.someObject`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that. I don't understand how changing `A.prototype.someObject` changes `Parent.prototype.someObject`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16800/discussion-between-clentfort-and-sime-vidas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, when you do this:

```
$.extend( true, A.prototype, {
    someObject: {Aone: 1, Atwo: 2}
});
```

this will happen as a result:

1. The properties `"Aone"`, and `"Atwo"` will be assigned to `Parent.prototype.someObject`, instead of `A.prototype.someObject` (which at that point doesn't event exist).
2. The property `A.prototype.someObject` will be created and its value will be set to `Parent.prototype.someObject`.

So, both `A.prototype.someObject`, and `Parent.prototype.someObject` will refer to the same object:

```
A.prototype.someObject === Parent.prototype.someObject // true
```

This is, of course, *not* what you want.

---

That being said, I'm concerned that your pattern is not good. `A.prototype` is supposed to *inherit* from `Parent.prototype`, yet you **copy** the values from `Parent.prototype.someObject` to `A.prototype.someObject`.

Also, your current solution:

```
A.prototype = $.extend( true, {}, A.prototype, {
    someObject: {Aone: 1, Atwo: 2}
});
```

is not intuitive. It's not easy to decipher what the code is doing. I recommend re-evaluating that pattern. (You can ask Stack Overflow for help, of course.)